# How to add a plugin to a component after render?

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework

I have a custom plugin that is to be added to a component after some event fires. The event fires after the component has been rendered to the page (it's not afterrender event though, it's a keyup event). So the plugin is also added after render. It seems that I need to refresh the component's configs somehow to make the plugin to take effect. Or may be there is another way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done but it is not supported by the api of a plugin.  In our code base we have a utility method that does this logic.  The plugin adder function is preferred when defining classes over `Ext.apply(this, {plugins: ...})` because extending and instantiated classes are allowed to add plugins on the fly though a config.

Here is it working with an override :

```
Ext.override(Ext.Component, {
    addPlugin: function(p) {
        //constructPlugin is private.
        //it handles the various types of acceptable forms for
        //a plugin
        var plugin = this.constructPlugin(p);
        this.plugins = Ext.Array.from(this.plugins);

        this.plugins.push(plugin);

        //pluginInit could get called here but
        //the less use of private methods the better
        plugin.init(this);

        return plugin;
    }
});
//EXAMPLE
Ext.define('PluginLogger', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    alias: 'plugin.logger',
    init: function(c) {
        console.log(c.plugins);
    }
});

var comp = new Ext.Component({
    plugins: 'logger'
});
//logs [plugin]

comp.addPlugin({
    ptype: 'logger'
});
// logs [plugin, plugin]
```